# Why is my paid Android app size hugely increased when downloaded from Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play, storage, apk

My paid Android app (.apk) size is 36 Mb but when downloaded from Google Play it is increased to 95 Mb in the phone !

I can see that the encrypted app file stored in data/app-asec is 70 Mb.

I use a single APK file which is created using the Export feature in Eclipse (Which handles signing and alignment). The 36 Mb is mostly graphics (.png).

I have added these settings to the manifest file:

```
android:installLocation="preferExternal"     (<manifest>)
android:allowBackup="false"                  (<application>)
```

I have included a PDF library (Approx. 10 MB).

When debugging my app using ADB the size in the phone is not increased (Still 36 Mb).